# Magento base_url not working

Tags: magento

I copied the production Magento application to my development machine. I changed the base_url in core_config_data table (2 rows). And I removed /var/cache/* in magento installation directory.

But when I go to www.my_dev.com/shop, it redirects me to www.my_production.com/shop.

Here's the core_config_data (I modified the URL to fake ones):

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data;
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                          | value                                                |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|         1 | default |        0 | general/region/display_all    | 1                                                    |
|         2 | default |        0 | general/region/state_required | AT,CA,CH,DE,EE,ES,FI,FR,LT,LV,RO,US                  |
|         3 | default |        0 | catalog/category/root_id      | 2                                                    |
|         4 | default |        0 | admin/dashboard/enable_charts | 1                                                    |
|         5 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url         | http://www.my_dev.com/shop/ |
|         6 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url           | http://www.my_dev.com/shop/ |
|         7 | default |        0 | general/locale/code           | en_US                                                |
|         8 | default |        0 | general/locale/timezone       | America/Los_Angeles                                  |
|         9 | default |        0 | currency/options/base         | USD                                                  |
|        10 | default |        0 | currency/options/default      | USD                                                  |
|        11 | default |        0 | currency/options/allow        | USD                                                  |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What did I miss?

Thanks.

Sam Kong

Comment: ping  www.my_dev.com/shop - what is the output? does your dev machine ip respond?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the database, check for core_config_data table. Ensure that `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` are set to `http://www.my_dev.com/shop` and `https://www.my_dev.com/shop` (you can also use http instead of https for the latter)
2. Check if the cookie domain is set to the right domain or left empty
3. Check .htaccess for some custom rewrites (basically you have to search for the `www.my_production.com/shop` string there and replace it with your production URL).

Let me know if any of this helps. If not, we will search for another solution.

Comment: Hi. How do I do #2? Just clear the cookies? #1 and #3 are confirmed to be ok.

Comment: Search for a row with web/cookie/cookie_domain as the value in the core_config_data table. If it's set to the right domain, it's NULL or it's not there at all, then it's good. Also, ensure that points 1 and 2 are not overwritten by some values set for website or store (rows with the same path in db, just with 'websites' or 'stores' instead of 'default' as a scope).

Comment: I added core_config_data to the original post. It seems fine. Any idea?

Comment: You could use a somewhat brute-force approach and search for www.my_production.com/shop in your entire code. Judging from your core_config_data your website is pretty new, but maybe someone was tinkering with it? Another thing that comes to my mind is the domain itself - it could be set to redirect to the production URL. Not a likely thing, but nothing better comes to my mind right now. I'll have to think about it for some more time.

Comment: You could also delete var/session to ensure that your session is new. Also, ensure that you don't have anything wrong in your app/var/etc directory - for example if you changed production local.xml to something other with an .xml extension, it will still be processed by Magento and may overwrite your config in your dev local.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you duplicated the database, as I do always, you should change the database in app/etc/local.xml with the development one where the domain, secure and unsecure, is www.my_dev.com/shop
This my common error when I do it in rush,
bye
Enrico